# Facebook Canvas App on Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a Facebook canvas app that allow users to write a custom Wall post and tag some friends. I'm familiar with stand alone rails apps, but I'm having a hard time grasping API interactions.

I've came across with a few gems (Facebooker2, Koala and fb_graph) and the Heroku integration that provide a easier way to use the GraphAPI, but I wasn't able to find updated examples on how to integrate them with a rails app from scratch. So far, the only one that I've found was this [sample from fb_graph](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph_sample).

It seems that this type of application is pretty common of Facebook, so I was expecting to find more info on the community. Is there a better way to start developing for Facebook using Rails or should I just pick one of those gems and stick with it until I grasp the concepts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create an Facebook canvas app using the fb_graph sample. Probably there are better solutions to handle Facebook authorization inside canvas, but the sample is a great start. Here is my project, a Music Quiz inside Facebook: https://github.com/luizbranco/MusicQuiz

Answer (score 0):

I built my first Facebook app from scratch using Koala. [Their wiki on Github](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki) is absolutely fantastic and everything is well explained.